# Type Class Pattern alternative for enriching ADT with methods in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

I wrote a basic *Algebraic Data Type* defined as follows

```
sealed trait Fruit {def name: String}
case class Apple(name: String) extends Fruit
case class Orange(name: String, color: String) extends Fruit
```

What I'd love to do is to define a common method across Apple and Orange. So I decided to offer this feature by a Type Class pattern.

```
sealed trait ServingFruit[T] {
    def peel(fruit: T): String
}

object FruitManager {
    def retrievePeelColor[T: ServingFruit](fruit: T): String =
        implicitly[ServingFruit[T]].peel(fruit)

    implicit object ApplePeelColor extends ServingFruit[Apple] {
        def peel(fruit: Apple): String = "GREEN"
    }

    implicit object OrangePeelColor extends ServingFruit[Orange] {
        def peel(fruit: Orange): String = fruit.color
    }
}
```

For a necessary (and unfortunate) constraint I have to handle fruits as **bounded instances of the shared base trait** `Fruit`

```
def myCodeMethod[F <: Fruit](fruit: F, out: String) = {
    import FruitManager._
    FruitManager.retrievePeelColor(fruit)
}
```

And it brings me to the following (somehow expected) exception.

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type my.path.to.fruit.ServingFruit[F] [error]FruitManager.retrievePeelColor(fruit)
```

Then, AFAIU [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413005/polymorphism-with-scala-type-classes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869991/type-class-pattern-in-scala-doesnt-consider-inheritance) Type Class Pattern is type independent and perhaps the latter is not well fitting my scenario.

The point is I'm struggling on figuring out a valuable solution to integrate my ADT with a common method available also to the base trait and - at the same time - I'd like to avoid providing the methods within the ADT (I'd try to stay FP oriented) and to use such workarounds as to add an additional `Fruit` converter to my Type Class.

Any help'd be really appreciated, thank you.

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the type class witness passed into `retrievePeelColor` as an implicit parameter:

```
scala> def retrievePeelColor[T](fruity: T)(implicit peeler: ServingFruit[T]) = peeler.peel(fruity)
retrievePeelColor: [T](fruity: T)(implicit peeler: ServingFruit[T])String

scala> retrievePeelColor(Apple("granny smith"))
res0: String = GREEN

scala> retrievePeelColor(Orange("bloody", "RED"))
res1: String = RED
```

And as for the design: I'm not an experienced design guy, but I wouldn't say that having some methods in a `sealed trait` isn't "FP style". If only fruits are peelable, and there are finitely many, it's OK to have one place for `peel`, IMHO (by this I'm talking about a method in `Fruit` matching on `this`, or a static member in the `Fruit` companion object).

Comment: This still don't solve the issue: if I call the method from `myCodeMethod` it still seeks for the implicit for evidence `ServingFruit[F]`, where `F <: Fruit`.

Of course neither I am a design expert, but I'd like to avoid to provide the method by declaring it in `Fruit` and defining it for each fruit, because I want to keep the logic the code semantic separated from the Fruit ADT.

Comment: Rename `FruitManager` to `ServingFruit` and it will work. Or just `import FruitManager._`